# touch event in box2d?

Tags: box2d

Is there any way to identify, whether a touch point is in a body in the world??

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you don't need to do something like that, because a body is always in the upper layer than the world if it exists, so if the point is both in a body and in the world, it must be the body to respond.